# Enumerate through a Data Source

Tags: c#, web, webforms

I've got a *Repeater Control* that will bind the contents at Page Load.

```
repeater.DataSource = Build<Model>(query);
repeater.DataBind();
```

*!! Important: Code has been minified, for brevity sake.*

The `Build<Model>` will build an `IEnumerable` of data from the database, which will be returned to the `DataSource`, which I bind so it is visible on the page.

On the front-end I have a button to trigger a search through the `DataSource` to rebind with the filtered result.

Would it be possible to do something:

```
IEnumerable<...> enumerator = repeater.DataSource.GetEnumerator();
```

Something along those lines?  That way I can loop through the contents, before I rebind with a filtered list?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do store the data source as a field to access later.

```
public class MyForm
{
   private MyDataSourceType myDataSource = null;

   private void SetDataModel()
   {
       myDataSource = Build<Model>(query);
       repeater.DataSource = myDataSource
       repeater.DataBind();
   }

   private void FilterDataSet()
   {
       IEnumerable<MyDataType> enumerated = myDataSource.GetEnumerator();
       var filteredDataSource; // Filter Logic here
       repeater.DataSource = filteredDataSource;
       repeater.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is pseudo code based upon your very brief code snippet.

Edit:
To work with DataSource, you can try this:

```
   private void FilterDataSet()
   {
       List<MyDataType> myDataSource = repeater.DataSource as List<MyDataType>;
       // Null check here
       IEnumerable<MyDataType> enumerated = myDataSource.GetEnumerator();
       var filteredDataSource; // Filter Logic here
       repeater.DataSource = filteredDataSource;
       repeater.DataBind();
   }
```

This will take repeater.DataSource (type of Object) and try to cast to your List (or whatever else it is). Do a null check, then GetEnumerator() and filter away.

Comment: I was thinking that, but thought it would be cleaner to access data source.